# Reading a txt and making a "list of lists"

Tags: python, list, configuration-files

I want to make a program that reads a `.txt` file that looks like this:

> [LIST 1]
>
> var1,var2,var3,var4
>
> var5,var6
>
> [LIST 2]
>
> var7,var8,var9

And as the title says, I want to make a list of all the terms between "[","]" and create a list for each of these terms composed of the terms listed under them (for example: `LIST2 = [var7, var8, var9]`).

So far, I made a list of the terms between "[]":

```
try:
f = open("tm.txt", "r")
try:
    string = f.read()       
finally:
    f.close()
except IOError:
    pass

lista = re.findall(re.escape("[")+"(.*)"+re.escape("]"),string)

for i in range(len(lista)):
    vars()[lista[i]] = i   #makes str into var and gives a value to them
    print vars()[lista[i]] #prints what is inside of each var of the list
print lista #prints each var names
```

As you can see, the only thing left to do is to assign each of these newly made variables to the list of terms that are under them on the `.txt` file. I'm trying to do that so I can make a configurator via `TKinter` for an Indie game I'm making. Editing the `.txt` files themselves is pretty annoying.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html might help you out

Comment: Why not use a dict of lists? And if your variables are key=value pairs, a dict of dicts. This would probably save a headache when using the data.

Answer (score 0):

From the examples section of the [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#examples) module:

```
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> import io
>>> s = """[LIST 1]
... 
... var1,var2,var3,var4
... 
... var5,var6
... 
... [LIST 2]
... 
... var7,var8,var9"""
>>> config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
>>> config.readfp(io.BytesIO(s))
>>> config.items('LIST 1')
[('var1,var2,var3,var4', None), ('var5,var6', None)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought you might don't have any intention to using Modules(like Myslef),So I Suggest This:

```
file1 = open('tm.txt')
flist = file1.readlines()
file1.close()
flist = [i.rstrip() for i in flist]
c = 0
final = []
for i in flist:
    if(i == '[LIST {0}]'.format(c+1)):
        temp = []
        final.append(temp)
        c += 1
    else:
        for j in i.split(','):
            temp.append(j)
            final[len(final)-1] = temp
print(final)

# Each Member OF 'final' List is The List You Want!
```